# Spacy - Importing/Exporting CSVs

Tags: python, pandas, spacy, xlsxwriter

I have been DIY learning python (and coding) for less than a week and as such please forgive if I'm being unintentionally vague.

My purpose is to use spacy to extract named entities, noun chunks, verbs, and adjectives from a CSV. I realize that for spacy to do its thing the import/export will be in a data frame format. Thanks to helpful resources online I've so far gotten to the following code:

```
import spacy
nlp=spacy.load('en')
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
#imported all the modules

emails=pd.read_csv('wassup.csv')
#defined the file
def explain_text_entities(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    for ent in doc.ents:
        print(f'Entity: {ent}, Label: {ent.label_},{spacy.explain(ent.label_)}')
#defined a named entity program

explain_text_entities(emails['text'][5])
#tested and this works to return me a sample analysis for the CSV file.
```

For context, column A in the CSV file has a header in row 1 ("rank") and column B has the header ("text") in row 1. Including the headers there are 338 rows.

I realize the above code only applies for identifying named entities in a CSV file. But any ideas how to proceed from here to add more functions and export this analysis to CSV? Spacy keeps saying it expects a string but I gave it a dataframe. Do you peeps have any resources that would be helpful, or any insight how to structure my code?

Thanks again!

Coltaine

Comment: try printing out the datatype of the parameter you are trying to pass. You can do this by typing:
print(type(emails['text'][5]))
this should ideally return <type,"str">

Comment: Thanks, Shire Dude. My main issue is exporting this data to a CSV. I try to print all the named entities in all 300 cells at one go like "explain_text_entities(emails['text'][:300])" but that doesn't seem to do the job. Do you know what command allows Spacy to batch process 300 cells at one go? Then export it to CSV?